# Rails - 2x belongs_to to the same model returns "undefined method `arel_table' for "User":String"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I have two models, `Game` and `User`.

Every game is happening between two users. I am trying to do the association this way:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_a_id'
  belongs_to :user, :class => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_b_id'
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_a, :class_name => 'Game'
  has_many :user_b, :class_name => 'Game'
end
```

But when I user this in the view:

```
@game.user_a.name
@game.user_b.name
```

the error on the output is:

```
undefined method `user_a' for #<Game:0x007feb73ce2b90>
```

How should be properly set up the associations between these two models to be able to display users as `@game.user_a.name`?

In the table `games` are columns `user_a` and `user_b`.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Why you used `has_many :user_a` and `has_many :user_b` associations in `User` class instead of `has_many :games_a` and `has_many :games_b`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create different association names:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_a, :class => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_a_id'
  belongs_to :user_b, :class => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_b_id'
end
```

And, in the `games` table, the columns names should be `user_a_id` and `user_a_id` as you declared as foreign keys in `Game` class.